# Error using MongoDB 3.4.2 with Java

Tags: java, eclipse, mongodb, maven

I am facing this issue while using MongoDB 3.4.2 in Java Maven Project

***The type com.mongodb.WriteConcern cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files***

here is the dependency added in pom.xml

```html
<dependency>
      <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
      <artifactId>mongodb-driver</artifactId>
      <version>3.4.2</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Is there is something I am missing?

Comment: I suspect the issue is due to "<scope>test</scope>". Are you trying to use this class in test code or dev code? If not, can you try using <scope>compile</scope> and let us know if you are still seeing the problem?

Comment: thanks for suggustion but it still not works
 I have changed the scope still no luck

Answer (score 0):

WriteConcern.class file is missing in downloaded jar. download 2.12 it has and working fine.